# Get Identifire of CMS Page if it is not active

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-pages

How to Get Identifier of CMS Page if it is not active.
Using CMS Page Collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
<?php   

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::app('admin'); 
 $collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 0);
 foreach ($collection as $cms)
    {
        echo $cms->getIdentifier().'<br />';
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, For Your Answer, But It Was Print Nothing

Comment: This is tested code 1.9 and it's working fine.Please check in backend for disables cms pages exist or not